# Merge array like common values from all arrays go first and then less common values afterwards and remaining values at the end using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

So I have a number of arrays. Let's say I have 3 arrays.

```
$array1 = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$array2 = array( 2, 3, 4 );
$array3 = array( 2, 5, 6 );
```

So 2 is in all the arrays. So I want it to be 1st value of new merged array, then 3 is common in `array1` & `array2`. I want result as below:

```
array( 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6 )
```

Comment: I don't know php, but the general approach: 1) concat the array 2) reduce it to a pair of the number and its occurence 3) sort this table by occurence number 4) map it to the number again

Answer (score 2):

1. merge the arrays ([array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge))
2. count the values ([array_count_values](https://www.php.net/array_count_values))
3. sort the values (reversed) and keep the keys ([arsort](https://www.php.net/arsort))
4. get the keys ([array_keys](https://www.php.net/array_keys))

```
    $array1 = array( 1, 2, 3 );
    $array2 = array( 2, 3, 4 );
    $array3 = array( 2, 5, 6 );

    $ar = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
    $counts = array_count_values($ar);
    arsort($counts);
    $output = array_keys($counts);

    var_dump($output);
```

Your output will be:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
  [5]=>
  int(6)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should resolves your problem:

```
$array1 = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$array2 = array( 2, 3, 4 );
$array3 = array( 2, 5, 6 );

$merged = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);

$result = array();

foreach($merged as $item) {
    if(!isset($result[$item])) {
        $result[$item] = 0;
    }

    $result[$item]++;
}

arsort($result);

print_r(array_keys($result));
```

Comment: From Php 7.4, you can swap out your if not isset assignment for the null coalescing equal operator. `$result[$item] ??= 0`.

Comment: @Progrock Could you please provide an example here?

Comment: @Bunty, my comment is a micro-optimisation replacing this block: `if(!isset($result[$item])) { $result[$item] = 0; }` with `$result[$item] ??= 0;`.  The foreach block above has the same outcome as array_count_values in @Dekel's answer.